# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Yii' not found in

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii2

I have Yii2 project with specific architecture.
So when I try to enter admin panel I got Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Yii' not found in W:\domains\localhost\Orders\mma\protected\modules\admin\views\default\login.php:2 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in W:\domains\localhost\Orders\mma\protected\modules\admin\views\default\login.php on line 2

Please help!
I trued to use Yii; and also \Yii:: but no result...

Thanks!

Comment: Please upload a minimal-project reproducing the issue (or at least, the file error mentions).

Comment: Excatly what do You need to help me? Project is 2 GB/

Comment: For example, start by uploading `login.php` file; Nevertheless, try `composer install` and then `composer dump-autoload --no-scripts`

Comment: I did it but no result

Comment: Looks like the project was cloned from git without installing dependencies. Check if you have composer.json file in root folder

Comment: If what you've posted in your question is whole stack trace then it looks like you are trying to access view template file directly instead of going properly through `index.php`. What url are you trying to access?